# How to count number of unique entries after merging two data.tables in R

Tags: r, data.table, data-wrangling

```
library(data.table)
table1 <- data.table(id1 = c(1324, 7822, 2324, 29, 9999, 1010, 1010),
                     class = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1),
                     type = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "C", "D", "D"),
                     number = c(1, 2.5, 98, 100, 80, 50, 70))
table2 <- data.table(id2 = c(1992, 1987, 1998, 1998, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2010, 2012, 2012),
                     class = c(3, 3, 1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 5, 1, 1),
                     type = c("B", "C", "D", "A", "D", "D", "C", "B", "A", "A"),
                     min_number = c(0, 0, 34, 0, 20, 45, 5, 23, 1, 1),
                     max_number = c(18, 18, 50, 100, 100, 100, 100, 9, 10, 8))
> table1
    id1 class type number
1: 1324     1    A    1.0
2: 7822     1    A    2.5
3: 2324     1    A   98.0
4:   29     2    B  100.0
5: 9999     2    C   80.0
6: 1010     1    D   50.0
7: 1010     1    D   70.0

> table2
     id2 class type min_number max_number
 1: 1992     3    B          0         18
 2: 1987     3    C          0         18
 3: 1998     1    D         34         50
 4: 1998     1    A          0        100
 5: 2000     3    D         20        100
 6: 2000     1    D         45        100
 7: 2000     2    C          5        100
 8: 2010     5    B         23          9
 9: 2012     1    A          1         10
10: 2012     1    A          1          8
```

For `id1` in `table1`, I would like to see how many matches there are based on `class`, `type`, and whether `number` falls between `min_number` and `max_number` in `table2`. I can see this more easily by first merging the two tables:

```
> table2[table1, on = c("class", "type", "max_number >= number", "min_number <= number")]
    id2 class type min_number max_number  id1
 1: 1998     1    A        1.0        1.0 1324
 2: 2012     1    A        1.0        1.0 1324
 3: 2012     1    A        1.0        1.0 1324
 4: 1998     1    A        2.5        2.5 7822
 5: 2012     1    A        2.5        2.5 7822
 6: 2012     1    A        2.5        2.5 7822
 7: 1998     1    A       98.0       98.0 2324
 8:   NA     2    B      100.0      100.0   29
 9: 2000     2    C       80.0       80.0 9999
10: 1998     1    D       50.0       50.0 1010
11: 2000     1    D       50.0       50.0 1010
12: 2000     1    D       70.0       70.0 1010
```

Examples:

- For `id1 = 1324`, there are 2 unique `id2`s that match:
  1998 and 2012.
- For `id1 = 29`, there are 0 `id2`s that match.
- For `id1 = 9999`, there is 1 `id2` that matches: 2000

The final desired output is that for each `id1`,

```
    id1 class type number nMatch
1: 1324     1    A    1.0      2
2: 7822     1    A    2.5      2
3: 2324     1    A   98.0      1
4:   29     2    B  100.0      0
5: 9999     2    C   80.0      1
6: 1010     1    D   50.0      2
```

This can be accomplished by 1) first merge the two tables and 2) count the number of unique, non-NA entries of `id2`.

```
merged_tables <- table2[table1, on = c("class", "type", "max_number >= number", "min_number <= number")]
> merged_tables %>% group_by(id1) %>% mutate(nMatch = n_distinct(id2[!is.na(id2)])) %>% select(id1, class, type, nMatch) %>% distinct()
# A tibble: 6 × 4
# Groups:   id1 [6]
    id1 class type  nMatch
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <int>
1  1324     1 A          2
2  7822     1 A          2
3  2324     1 A          1
4    29     2 B          0
5  9999     2 C          1
6  1010     1 D          2
```

**My question is: is there a way to do this without first merging the two tables?** The reason is because in practice, `table1` and `table2` have millions of rows, so merging them is inefficient.

My attempt:

```
> table2[table1, on = c("class", "type", "max_number >= number", "min_number <= number"), .(id1, nMatch = uniqueN(id2[!is.na(id2)])), by = .(id1)]
Error in eval(bysub, xss, parent.frame()) : object 'id1' not found
```

Comment: You write both "For each row in table1" and "for each id1 [in table1]", which may or may not be the same thing. Where did id = 1010 & number = 70.0 go in the "final desired output"? That said, it seems that you are looking for `by = .EACHI`; `table2[table1, on = c("class", "type", "max_number >= number", "min_number <= number"), .(id1, uniqueN(id2[!is.na(id2)])), by = .EACHI]`
Cheers

Comment: @Henrik Sorry, I meant "for each id1 in table1" not "for each row in table1". That's why there's no "id = 1010 & number = 70" in the desired output. I'm revising the original post - thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: would a unique on any of the tables make any difference, taking the merge variables only?

Comment: @Adrian You'll run into https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/733 if you want your answer by id instead of by row.

Comment: What is the issue with the current solution, time or memory limitations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If memory is an issue you could work row by row:

```
setindexv(table2, c("class", "type"))
for (t1_row in seq_len(nrow(table1))) {
  set(
    table1, t1_row, "matches",
    table2[table1[t1_row], on = c("class", "type", "max_number >= number", "min_number <= number"), .(list(id2))]
  )
}
table1[, .(nMatch = uniqueN(unlist(matches), na.rm = TRUE)), by = .(id1, class, type)]
#      id1 class   type nMatch
#    <num> <num> <char>  <int>
# 1:  1324     1      A      2
# 2:  7822     1      A      2
# 3:  2324     1      A      1
# 4:    29     2      B      0
# 5:  9999     2      C      1
# 6:  1010     1      D      2
```