# How to quickly count number of unique entries after merging tables

Tags: r, merge, data.table

```
library(data.table)
table1 <- data.table(id1 = c(1324, 2324, 29, 29, 1010, 1010),
                     type = c(1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1),
                     class = c("A",  "A", "B", "D", "D", "A"),
                     number = c(1, 98, 100, 100, 70, 70))
table2 <- data.table(id2 = c(1998, 1998, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2010, 2012, 2012),
                     type = c(1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1),
                     class = c("D", "A", "D", "D", "A", "B", "A", "A"),
                     min_number = c(34, 0, 20, 45, 5, 23, 1, 1),
                     max_number = c(50, 100, 100, 100, 100, 9, 10, 100))

> table1
    id1 type class number
1: 1324    1     A      1
2: 2324    1     A     98
3:   29    2     B    100
4:   29    1     D    100
5: 1010    1     D     70
6: 1010    1     A     70
> table2
    id2 type class min_number max_number
1: 1998    1     D         34         50
2: 1998    1     A          0        100
3: 2000    3     D         20        100
4: 2000    1     D         45        100
5: 2000    1     A          5        100
6: 2010    5     B         23          9
7: 2012    1     A          1         10
8: 2012    1     A          1        100
```

I have two tables, and I would like to merge them based on `type`, `class`, and whether `number` lies between `min_number` and `max_number`. Then I would like to create a new variable `nMatch` that stores the number of unique `id2`s that match with each `id1`.

```
setindexv(table2, c("type", "class"))
for (t1_row in seq_len(nrow(table1))) {
  print(t1_row)
  set(
    table1, t1_row, "matches",
    table2[table1[t1_row], on = c("type", "class", "max_number >= number", "min_number <= number"), .(list(id2))]
  )
}
> table1[, .(nMatch = uniqueN(unlist(matches), na.rm = TRUE)), by = .(id1)]
    id1 nMatch
1: 1324      2
2: 2324      3
3:   29      1
4: 1010      3
```

The approach above is row-by-row as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74250585/how-to-count-number-of-unique-entries-after-merging-two-data-tables-in-r), but my real dataset has millions of rows. What's another way of doing this that's faster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `data.table` with `on = .(...)` to merge two data tables

```
table1[
  table2,
  .(id1, id2),
  on = .(type, class, number >= min_number, number <= max_number),
  nomatch = NULL
][
  ,
  .(nMatch = uniqueN(id2)),
  id1
]
```

and will get

```
    id1 nMatch
1: 1324      2
2: 1010      3
3: 2324      3
4:   29      1
```

Comment: @Henrik Thanks for your feedback! Yes, you are right. It seems I overthought about the question. The answer is updated!

Answer (score 0):

An option with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
left_join(table1, table2, by = 
   join_by(type, class, number >= min_number, number <= max_number)) %>% 
  distinct(id1, id2) %>%
  drop_na %>%
  count(id1, name = "nMatch")
```

-output

```
     id1 nMatch
   <num>  <int>
1:    29      1
2:  1010      3
3:  1324      2
4:  2324      3
```